# MySQL optimize query with min and limit in a trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have this mysql query:

```
SELECT MIN(v.ifr) FROM (SELECT v.ifr FROM tbl_valuation v WHERE v.stock_id = 1 ORDER BY v.created_at DESC LIMIT 19) as v;
```

The query explain:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL  |   19 |   100.00 | NULL                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | v          | NULL       | ref  | idx_stock     | idx_stock  | 9       | const | 2873 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

The problem is, this query and others similar to this one are in a trigger, so, before every insert this queries runs and updates some values.
The trigger is activate about thousand times per minute.

After 1m records, it's getting slow, maybe because mysql go through about 54587 rows.

There's a way to optmize this query?

this is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BUY_WARNING_TRIG BEFORE INSERT 
ON tbl_valuation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE warn_counter INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE min_ifr DECIMAL(17,12);
    DECLARE min_lgui DECIMAL(17,12);
    DECLARE stock VARCHAR(100);    

    IF New.ls >= New.macd THEN
        SELECT MIN(v.ifr) 
            FROM (SELECT v.ifr FROM tbl_valuation v WHERE v.stock_id = New.stock_id ORDER BY v.created_at DESC LIMIT 9) as v INTO min_ifr;

        IF New.ifr <= min_ifr THEN
            SELECT MIN(v.lgui) 
                FROM (SELECT v.lgui FROM tbl_valuation v WHERE v.stock_id = New.stock_id ORDER BY v.created_at DESC LIMIT 9) as v INTO min_lgui;

            IF New.lgui <= min_lgui THEN
                SET warn_counter = warn_counter + 1;
            END IF;
        END IF;

        SELECT MIN(v.ifr) FROM (SELECT v.ifr FROM tbl_valuation v WHERE v.stock_id = New.stock_id ORDER BY v.created_at DESC LIMIT 4) as v INTO min_ifr;

        IF New.ifr <= min_ifr THEN
            SELECT MIN(v.lgui) 
                    FROM (SELECT v.lgui FROM tbl_valuation v WHERE v.stock_id = New.stock_id ORDER BY v.created_at DESC LIMIT 4) as v INTO min_lgui;

            IF New.lgui <= min_lgui THEN
                SET warn_counter = warn_counter + 1;
            END IF;
        END IF;

        SELECT MIN(v.ifr) FROM (SELECT v.ifr FROM tbl_valuation v WHERE v.stock_id = New.stock_id ORDER BY v.created_at DESC LIMIT 19) as v INTO min_ifr;

        IF New.ifr <= min_ifr THEN
            SELECT MIN(v.lgui) 
                    FROM (SELECT v.lgui FROM tbl_valuation v WHERE v.stock_id = New.stock_id ORDER BY v.created_at DESC LIMIT 19) as v INTO min_lgui;

            IF New.lgui <= min_lgui THEN
                SET warn_counter = warn_counter + 1;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    IF warn_counter > 0 THEN
        SELECT t.stock FROM tbl_stock t WHERE t.id = New.stock_id INTO stock;
        CASE warn_counter
            WHEN 1 THEN INSERT INTO tbl_warning (created_at, stock, level, rate, `type`) VALUES (NOW(), stock, 'LOW', New.rate, 'BUY');
            WHEN 2 THEN INSERT INTO tbl_warning (created_at, stock, level, rate, `type`) VALUES (NOW(), stock, 'MED', New.rate, 'BUY');
            WHEN 3 THEN INSERT INTO tbl_warning (created_at, stock, level, rate, `type`) VALUES (NOW(), stock, 'HIGH', New.rate, 'BUY');
        END CASE;
    END IF;
END$$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query absolutely requires an index `tbl_valuation (stock_id, created_at)` (in that order) that supports both `where`-condition and the `order by`. This will get rid of `Using filesort`.

To make it a bit faster, you should include the other two columns you use in your queries, `tbl_valuation (stock_id, created_at, ifr, lgui)`, to make it a covering index. This will save the time to lookup these values in the table (and will show up as `using index`).

Since you are basically executing a very similar query 6 times, your trigger code itself can probably also be optimized by reorganizing it or using a different method, although I am not going to do that. One quick optimization though: you can cut the number of queries in half by combining the query for `lgui` and `ifr`:

```
 SELECT min(v.ifr), min(v.lgui) into min_ifr, min_lgui 
 FROM (SELECT v.ifr, v.lgui 
       FROM tbl_valuation v WHERE v.stock_id = new.stock_id 
       ORDER BY v.created_at DESC LIMIT 9) as v
```

It won't cost you any time to do it, so if you do not need the `min_lgui`-value in the next step, there is no harm done, but if you do need it, you save one `select`.

Comment: thank you, with this index added my response time decresed by half.